# Login from Different Databases Yii2

Tags: php, database, authentication, yii2

I want to use two tables from different databases for login feature in Yii2 basic app.

In the login view, I add a new field:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username') ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'choice') ?>
```

In the LoginForm, I modify this:

```
public function getUser() {
    if ($this->_user === false && $this->choice == 1) {            
        $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
    }

    else if ($this->_user === false && $this->choice == 2) {
        $this->_user = UserPerusahaan::findByUsername($this->username);
    }

    return $this->_user;
}
```

The User.php has this:

```
public static function getDb() {
    return \Yii::$app->dblogin;  // use the "db2" application component
}

public static function tableName() {
    return 'pengguna';
}
```

What makes UserPerusahaan.php different from User.php is this:

```
/*public static function getDb() {
    return \Yii::$app->dblogin; 
}*/

public static function tableName() {
    return 'perusahaan';
}
```

When I try logging in it just refreshes the login page.
What am I missing here? Or is there another better practical approach?

**EDIT:**

I tried adding this to components in web.php:

```
'user' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\User',
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
],
'userperusahaan' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\User',
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\UserPerusahaan',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
 ],
```

And this to LoginForm.php:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->validate()&& $this->choice == 1) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
    }
    else if ($this->validate()&& $this->choice == 2) {
        return Yii::$app->userperusahaan->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The login using $choice = 1 works, but using $choice = 2 still gives me refreshed login page.

Comment: this link maybe help you to use multiple indentity in Yii2 https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2545/using-multiple-models-in-an-identity and this https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/864/how-to-login-from-different-tables-in-yii2?revision=7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use that scenario, avoid using roles "@" in your accessControl. Roles "@" only applied to Yii::$app->user, so if you login with different component (such as Yii::$app->userPerusahaan->login()) it will not count as registered user with roles "@". Modified your siteController like this example.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['index', 'login'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

public function actionIndex()
{
    if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest && Yii::$app->userPerusahaan->isGuest) return $this->redirect(['login']);
    //  ......
```

Comment: Sage advice. Thanks, Kak.